# RxJava2.1.0 : PublishSubject onNext not invoked when subscribed on different threads

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

It is found that when subscribing to a serialized PublishSubject within 10-20 ms of invoking onNext events on the Subjects; the new subscriber's onNext is not invoked.

In the code snippet below; the value to observe[1] is given as "2000" and subscribeToSubject() is invoked after calling onNext() on the Subject with the value 1998 [2]; we see that if the interval is 10ms the new subscribers will miss the value 2000 being fired by the Subject; Whereas, if the interval is 50ms or greater then the new subscribers seems to receive the expected values; Is this an expected behavior?

This behavior is seen on RxJava 2.1.0; Appears to be some kind of race-condition

```
public class PublishSubjectTest {

    private final Subject<String> singlePropertyUpdateSubject =
            PublishSubject.<String>create().toSerialized();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PublishSubjectTest obj= new PublishSubjectTest();
        obj.sendEvents();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


//[1]
    private final String valueToObserve = "2000";
    private void subscribeToSubject() {
        System.out.println("Subscribing .....");
        io.reactivex.Observable.range(1,10).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(
                value -> getAndObserve(valueToObserve).subscribe(observedValue -> System.out.println("  Value Received   "+observedValue +" By "+Thread.currentThread() ))
        );



    }

    private io.reactivex.Observable<String> getAndObserve(String value) {
        final io.reactivex.Observable<String> observable = singlePropertyUpdateSubject
                //.doOnNext(v-> System.out.println("Received value "+v))
                .filter(v -> v.equals(value))
                .doOnSubscribe(c-> System.out.println("Consumer subscribed "+c));
        return observable;
    }


// 50ms >= expected result ;  Anything less than 10ms will fail.
    private void sendEvents() {
        io.reactivex.Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(value -> {
            String key = value.toString();
            //System.out.println("Adding key "+key);
            singlePropertyUpdateSubject.onNext(key);
//[2]           
 if (value == 1998){
                subscribeToSubject();;
            }
            if (value%100==0) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok, the issue is with PublishSubject;  use of BehaviourSubject / ReplaySubject seems to fix this problem;  there is also an issue with application calling system.exit(1) when using Replay/Behaviour Subject ;  Detailed discussion is provided https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6414

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP triple- posted it on the RxJava issue list because of impatience. The OP received adequate feedback there.

Comment: yes please close it;  It may not be due to impatience, perhaps the fact that the issue was closed straightway; A closed issue may not consider to have a valid correspondence thread. 

Regarding above issue;  It appears the BehaviourSubject does seem to have the problem ; Use of ReplaySubject seems to have fixed it, feedback in RxJava list was very useful. 

I don't know how to close this issue, if so I would do it.

Comment: I automatically close issues that have been cross posted on SO and the RxJava issue list.

Comment: I'm sorry for cross-posting it on SO; I think I missed the description in GitHub when I made the original post.  I can see you have mentioned it on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue is with PublishSubject; use of ReplaySubject seems to fix this problem of concurrent subscription; there is also an issue with the test code  calling system.exit(1) when using ReplaySubject ; Detailed discussion is provided github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6414 –

please consider this issue as closed.